# how to make a *.dll WinAmp plugin work on a friends pc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-studio-2013

I just made this very simple .dll plugin  for Winamp. It works perfectly fine on my pc but I made it for a friend who requested this. Its the first time I use Visual Studio 2013
and make dll files with c++... my problem is that i can't really figure out why it doesn't work on his pc, I think its an export problem but I am not entirely sure.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "gen_InfinitePlay.h"
#include "wa_ipc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;


// these are callback functions/events which will be called by Winamp
int  init(void);
void config(void);
void quit(void);


// this structure contains plugin information, version, name...
// GPPHDR_VER is the version of the winampGeneralPurposePlugin (GPP) structure
winampGeneralPurposePlugin plugin = {
    GPPHDR_VER,  // version of the plugin, defined in "gen_InfinitePlay.h"
    PLUGIN_NAME, // name/title of the plugin, defined in "gen_InfinitePlay.h"
    init,        // function name which will be executed on init event
    config,      // function name which will be executed on config event
    quit,        // function name which will be executed on quit event
    0,           // handle to Winamp main window, loaded by winamp when this dll is loaded
    0            // hinstance to this dll, loaded by winamp when this dll is loaded
};

void play(){
    while (true){
        if (SendMessage(plugin.hwndParent, WM_WA_IPC, 0, IPC_ISPLAYING) != 1)
            SendMessage(plugin.hwndParent, WM_WA_IPC, 0, IPC_STARTPLAY);
        Sleep(60000);
    }
}
// event functions follow

int init() {


        Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(play));
        t->Start();

    return 0;
}

void config() {
    //A basic messagebox that tells you the 'config' event has been triggered.
    //You can change this later to do whatever you want (including nothing)
    //MessageBox(plugin.hwndParent, L"Config event triggered for gen_InfinitePlay.", L"", MB_OK);
}

void quit() {
    //A basic messagebox that tells you the 'quit' event has been triggered.
    //If everything works you should see this message when you quit Winamp once your plugin has been installed.
    //You can change this later to do whatever you want (including nothing)
    //MessageBox(0, L"Quit event triggered for gen_InfinitePlay.", L"", MB_OK);
}


// This is an export function called by winamp which returns this plugin info.
// We wrap the code in 'extern "C"' to ensure the export isn't mangled if used in a CPP file.
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) winampGeneralPurposePlugin * winampGetGeneralPurposePlugin() {
    return &plugin;
}
```

Comment: define "doesn't work" pls

Comment: well thats all i got... the problem is that the .dll file is placed in the winamp/plugin dir and when I open Winamp there is nothing like a error message, its not even loading. On my pc it works perfectly though.

Comment: Could be a problem with mixing compilers ( precautions must be made to use more than 1 compiler in the same application ) or not having the VS 2013 runtime installed.

Comment: Where is your entry function?

Comment: Sounds like a missing dependency, use something like dependency walker to find out if you have a dependency on a library that is present on your computer but not his.

Comment: what is an entry function?

Comment: I used the Dependency Filewalker and it says that MSVCR120.DLL is missing
also IESHIMS.DLL but thats missing on my pc too so it shouldn't be the problem

Comment: MSVCR120.DLL must be on your PC if you have Visual Studio 2013. This is the runtime for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Visual Studio 2013 runtime. The proper way to install this is via the Visual Studio 2013 redistributable.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Answer (score 0):

MSVCR120.DLL was missing, its probably not the "right" way to make it work but I just copied mine to his plugin dir... I still think it could be solved by some export flags or something but I am to lazy for this